# How do I reload kerberos configuration under tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, jndi, kerberos

My application runs under tomcat.
It is using GSS API (JNDI) to connect to Active Directory LDAP Server using Kerberos.
It allows the user to define AD servers and try to connect to them.
However, once the first Kerberos using connect attempt is done, the application does not read Kerberos configuration again (`/etc/krb5.conf`).
Hence, any change to it requires a restart of tomcat.

How can I avoid such a restart ? How can I force the application to reload Kerberos configuration before each connect attempt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem too! See this related StackOverflow post, hope the above link helps.

[Reload Kerberos config in JAVA without restarting JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437281/reload-kerberos-config-in-java-without-restarting-jvm)